# How to force compile-warnings if not all public things are JavaDoc'd?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, warnings, javadoc

I want to get warnings at compile time for every public thing (class, interface, field, method) which doesn't have a Javadoc comment.

How can I enable this in Eclipse?

Comment: you can use PMD for this .http://pmd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Its a setting somewhere in eclipse, I have done it before without downloading any plugins

Comment: hey dude you need accept the answer of the guy below by clicking the transparent tick mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your tag, I'll assume that you mean in Eclipse.  To do so, Open the Window -> Preferences Menu Item, and then Under Java -> Compiler -> Javadoc, there will be a dropdown that will either let you treat missing javadoc tags as Error, Warning, or Ignore.

This answer was for the latest version of eclipse, but if you search for javadoc in the preferences search you should be able to find it easily enough.

Comment: Thank you, I found it at the same time as you posted, but helpful none the less.